# RxJS map is not running a function

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, but in my `map` function I want to call `_filter()`. The way I have it below, it works just fine, however I want to call filter even if item is `falsy`.

The below example is based on the [Chips Input](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/examples) from material.

```js
export type ChipItem = string | { label: string, [key: string]: any; };

export class ExampleComponent {
  selections = ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Orange'];
  filteredItems: Observable<ChipItem[]>;
  itemsCtrl = new FormControl();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredItems = this.itemsCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map((item: ChipItem) => item ? this._filter(item) : this.selections)
    );
  }

  private _filter(value?: ChipItem): ChipItem[] {
    console.log('here');

    // Apply filtering (this works).
    return this.selections.filter(i => /* Filter logic */)
  }
}
```

When I click on the input I would like to run the filter to filter out items that are already selected (The code for that is already in the filter). The filter works with the above but not the below.

If I change my `map` to the following, then `_filter()` never gets called.

```js
map((item: ChipItem) => this._filter(item))
```

The html:

```html
  <input 
    fxFlex="0 1" 
    #chipInput
    [formControl]="itemsCtrl" 
    [matAutocomplete]="auto" 
    (keyup.enter)="add($event)">

  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let val of filteredItems | async" [value]="val">
      {{val.label || val}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Where are you subscribing to the observable?

Comment: Something's not adding up :-)  Whenever `.valueChanges` emits, `map()` should call your function.  What's up with `startWith('')`?  Maybe you could better illustrate with a StackBlitz?

Comment: @NicholasK I have added some updates.

Comment: If I remove `startWith()`, it works when I type something into the input, however, it doesn't work when I focus on the input.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you need an Observable for the options, to start with, but if you want to handle the case when the valueChanges does not emit a (true) value, you can use [filter](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/filter) to prevent emission:

```
this.filteredItems = this.itemsCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
  filter(Boolean),
  map((item: ChipItem) => this.selections) // or some other logic 
);
```

That way you do not need to handle the case where item is null or false or undefined ( or any  falsey value), and do not need your custom filter function.